# trigger grid itemcreated event from code using telerik

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

In a grid with emp details. the row in which `empid=1`. I would want to edit that row in the datagrid.

There is already edit functionality written in `GridName_itemCreated(Object sender,gridItemEventArgs e)` for a different scenario

```
protected void gProc_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
     {
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about what your question is?

Comment: Checking a condition i want to trigger this event and have the values "e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode" true. how can i achive this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference the actual data being bound to the row (the emp... in order to get its id), then you're using the wrong event. You need ItemDataBound rather than ItemCreated.

```
void gProc_ItemDataBound(Object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e) 
{
    var emp = e.Item.DataItem;
    //...
}
```

Comment: the data is already being loaded into the grid on page load by using itemdatabound method. but later i want to add a new row into the table and the row has to be editable.